# Proving by induction that $\sum_{i=2}^n(i^2-i) = \frac{n(n^2-1)}{3}$ for all $n \ge 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Doing proof by induction exercises, everything was fine until I tried to do one with $\sum$
:

> Prove that
>
> $$\sum_{i=2}^n(i^2-i) = \frac{n(n^2-1)}{3}$$
>
> holds for all $n \ge 2$.

Now, my real problem is converting an algebraic expression to another (see bottom of question), but if you're curious here's the whole process.

---

Test it for $n = 2$:

$$\sum_{i=2}^2(i^2-i) = \frac{2(2^2-1)}{3}$$

$$(2^2-2) = \frac{2\cdot3}{3}$$

$$2 = \frac{6}{3}$$

---

We have to prove that it holds for $n + 1$, that is:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}(i^2-i) = \frac{(n+1)((n+1)^2-1)}{3}$$

---

Assume

$$\sum_{i=2}^n(i^2-i) = \frac{n(n^2-1)}{3}$$

---

Prove it. Have:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}(i^2-i)$$

Okay so, I normally attempt to use the hypothesis to make some replacement, but to do so I need to expand a bit this sum. I will try separating the last element in the sum, which I think would be like this:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}(i^2-i) + \color{blue}{((n+1)^2-(n+1))}$$

Because, it seems to me, that in the last element of the sum, the $i$ would be $(n+1)$.

Now I can make the replacement with the hypothesis that I wanted:

$$\color{blue}{\frac{n(n^2-1)}{3}} + ((n+1)^2-(n+1))$$

$$\frac{n(n^2-1)+3((n+1)^2-(n+1))}{3}$$

Not sure. I'll just try expanding that quadratic.

$$\frac{n(n^2-1)+3(n^2+2n+1-n-1)}{3}$$

$$\frac{n(n^2-1)+3(n^2+n)}{3}$$

$$\frac{n(n^2-1)+(3n^2+3n)}{3}$$

$$\frac{n^3-n+3n^2+3n}{3}$$

$$\frac{n^3+3n^2+2n}{3}$$

$$\frac{n^3+3n^2 + 2n}{3}$$

$$\frac{n^2(n+3)+2n}{3}$$

---

It does seem to me like this last expression is indeed equivalent to what I want to prove $\frac{(n+1)((n+1)^2-1)}{3}$, but I can't seem to figure how to transform it into that. How can I proceed?

Comment: what i would suggest is.. while doing induction problems if you are sure that what you have done up to the point is correct and you guess you need two/three steps, it will alwasy be a good idea to going backwards.... as you know what you are going to conclude...

Answer (score 4):

Even better, going forwards:

$$ \begin{align}n^3+3n^2+2n&=n(n^2+3n+2)\\&=n(n+2)(n+1)\tag{1}\\&=((n+1)^2-1)(n+1)\tag{2}\end{align} $$

We can go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ by difference of two squares.

Answer (score 1):

MY approach:

first show that $\sum^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $ and $\sum^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n +1 )}{6} $.
To show then, it is much easier the induction. So, therefore

$$ \sum^n (i^2 - i) = \sum^n i^2 - \sum^n i = \frac{n(n+1)(2n +1 )}{6} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} =   $$

$$ = \frac{n(n+1)(2n-1) - 3n(n+1)}{6} = \frac{(n+1)(2n^2 + n - 3n )}{6} = \frac{(n+1)(2n^2 - 2n)}{6} =$$

$$ = \frac{(n+1)(n^2 - n)}{3} = \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{3} = \frac{n(n^2-1)}{3}$$

Comment: -1. The asker is probably learning in USA. etc., etc.